# Fastest way to check multiple digits in a number

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to achieve the following (making sure a number only has certain digits by passing the excluded digits to IndexOf)?

```
function notInArray(num, arr){
    var numStr = num.toString();
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i<l; i++){
        if (numStr.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1 ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(notInArray(333331, [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])); //false
```

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?  Easiest to read?  Lowest cpu cycles?

Comment: Most efficient. It seems like it could be done with a regex or another more obvious native function that I am missing (e.g. if you can already pass an array to IndexOf without rewriting it)

Comment: Your question title is a bit misleading, would you mind to fix it (e. g. "Fastest way to check digits in a number")? You might get more & better answers :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using a RegEx?

```
function notInArray(num, arr)
{
    return !(new RegExp(arr.join("|"), "g").test(num));
}

console.log(notInArray(333331, [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]));
```

So breaking it out, what it does:

1. `num = 333331`
2. `arr = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]`
3. `arr.join("|")` = `"1|2|4|6|7|8|9|0"`
4. `new RegExp(arr.join("|"), "g")` = `/1|2|4|6|7|8|9|0/g`
5. `new RegExp(arr.join("|"), "g").test(num)` = `/1|2|4|6|7|8|9|0/g.test(num)` which basically checks if each digit exists in the number

If it does, meaning `true`, then invert it and return that.

Comment: I just rant that through benchmarkjs - wonder if I created the test wrong :) ? loop x 4,359,371 ops/sec ±5.79% (55 runs sampled)
regex x 373,362 ops/sec ±4.65% (61 runs sampled)
Fastest is loop

Comment: That one is better than first, but the loop still seems to win handily:loop x 4,365,301 ops/sec ±5.58% (60 runs sampled)
regex2 x 644,998 ops/sec ±3.79% (65 runs sampled)
Fastest is loop

Comment: Try compiling the RegExp outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only dealing with digits you can use bitmasks, that way the check for each digit of `num` is done in constant time

```
function notInArray(num, arr) {
    var mask = 0
    var i, l
    for (i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i += 1) {
      mask |= (1 << arr[i])
    }
    var numStr = num.toString();
    for (i = 0, l = numStr.length; i < l; i += 1) {
      var bit = 1 << Number(numStr[i])
      if (mask & bit) return false
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(notInArray(333331, [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])) //false
```

Comment: That's great - definitely going to experiment with this one on larger sets. If you are curious on benchmark (the way I've been running it with only one simple test): loop x 4,179,439 ops/sec ±4.29% (61 runs sampled)
bit x 3,133,173 ops/sec ±5.17% (58 runs sampled) Fastest is loop

Answer (score 0):

Combination of my approach and @Mauricio Poppe's excellent bitmask idea:

```js
/**
 * Check if the given number does not contain any of the specified digits.
 *
 * @param number Integer number in [0-Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER]
 * @param digits Array of accepted digits in [0-9]  
 */
function checkDigits(number, digits) {
  var mask = 0, i, l;
  for (i = 0, l = digits.length; i < l; ++i) {
    mask |= (1 << digits[i]);
  }
  while (number > 9) {
    l = number % 10;
    if (mask & (1 << l)) return false;
    number *= 0.1;
  }
  return !(mask & (1 << number));
}

console.log(checkDigits(333331, [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])); // False
console.log(checkDigits(0, [0])); // False
console.log(checkDigits(9007199254740991, [1, 2, 3])); // False
console.log(checkDigits(0, [1])); // True
console.log(checkDigits(135, [2, 4, 6])); // True
console.log(checkDigits(9007199254740991, [3, 6, 8])); // True
```

Remember: `checkDigits(01, [1])` returns true since 01 === 1.

Comment: loop x 1,303,934 ops/sec ±1.89% (85 runs sampled)
opLoop x 9,108,076 ops/sec ±3.85% (79 runs sampled)

Answer (score 0):

If you believe like me that in order to obtain the individual digits of a number, converting it into string is not a chivalrous attitude then you might find yourself writing a recursive code. So again what do you mean by asking "what is the best way..?" The following might turn out slow but it's like poem to me.

```js
var n = 333331,
    a = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
 nina = (n,a) => !~a.indexOf(~~(n%10)) && (n < 10 || nina(n/10,a));
 
 console.log(nina(n,a));
```

Well OK here comes a contribution from me to the string society. I first construct a lut (hash  table) then apply `Array.prototype.some()`

```js
var n = 333331,
    a = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
 nina = (n,a) => {var h = [...""+n].reduce((p,c) => (p[c] = true,p),{});
                  return !a.some(e => h[e])};
console.log(nina(n,a));
```

Comment: Well, the OP is after speed. But it would be interesting to have it benchmarked. Also: `const notinarray = (n,a) => ![...(''+n)].some(x => a.some(y => ''+y === x));` The string conversions aren't ideal, as you note.

Comment: @FizzyTea Cool cool... but again... if you convert the number to string then there are tons of ways to skin this cat. OK i will attach a fast option to my answer.

Comment: One issue with using binary operators is that they restrict the range of n from Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER (= 9007199254740991) to the maximum 32-bit two-complement (= 2147483647). You can circumvent that by applying ~~ to the argument of a.indexOf() instead.

Comment: @le_m: This is a very valid point... Thank you. I will amend accordingly.